# How to call methods in android library by web service?

Tags: android, web-services, static-libraries

I had created an android library project that is used to browse images through `gallery` or from `camera`. This browsed image will be compressed and then uploaded to the server. Now, I want to access the method in above mentioned library through `web service` made in `asp.net`. Is it possible and if yes, how??

or 
Is there a way to add jar file to the web service and used it's method??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. I've worked on Webservices made in php and SOAP which returned me a JSON object on calling. Calling .net services are relatively simpler. You should search in stackoverflow or google for particular answer. Here are some of the questions I found.

[how to use Get method for calling web services in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524401/how-to-use-get-method-for-calling-web-services-in-android?rq=1)
[Call .NET Webservice with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992258/call-net-webservice-with-android)

Comment: I'm asking for for calling web service from android application, But the other way around. How to call method in android library project by web service

Comment: I think you need to have a service running on the target device which can check the server calls every few minutes (let's say 5 mins). I don't know if push notifications can be used to achieve this or not, never used them before. But they can come in handy too.

Comment: if you can give an working example, it would be of great help. thanks